# Datatable not getting updated automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, datatables

on adding the item, datagrid doesn't update automatically. On refreshing only record appears.
what needs to be done in the below code to auto update the table withou refreshing.
The url is the rest api I call to add the item

```js
function addItem(){

var data = null;

var addItem = new XMLHttpRequest();
addItem.withCredentials = true;

var eName = $('#txtempname').val();  
    var eDesg = $('#txtdesignation').val();  
 
 
addItem.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

addItem.open("POST", "url");
addItem.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic cGR4OnBkeA==");
addItem.setRequestHeader("name", eName);
addItem.setRequestHeader("description",eDesg );
addItem.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
addItem.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "320fb698-18d9-790b-3471-3528ec60d948");

addItem.send(data);

 $.ajax(
                {
                 type:'POST',
                   url: 'url',

                   success:function(){
                     
                    //s console.log("added succesfully");
swal("Added!", "Catalog Added successfully", "success");
            getItems();  

  
            if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#subsiteList')) {  
                $('#subsiteList').DataTable().destroy();  
            }  
            $('#subsiteList tbody').empty();   
 
                   },
                   error:function(){
                      console.log("error");
                   }
                }
              );


}
```

Comment: Can you please show how you are adding Data in datatable.

Comment: the html part? or the  fetching data from rest part?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
    
        var html = "<tr><td><a onclick='getvalue(this);' class='button js-button' role='button' href='productadd.html?"+data.items[i].id+"' </tr>";
        $('.table tbody').append(html);

    }  table = $('#subsiteList').DataTable();

Comment: @MyTwoCents any solution?

Comment: is something wrong with the ajax being used in the function

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should take refrence from my solution to a similar question posted below : - [Refrence link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390601/why-my-jquery-datatable-shows-data-at-first-attempt-but-not-for-the-subsequent-a/53392618#53392618)